# Checkout GIT repository through Internet

Tags: git, remote-access, git-remote

We use GIT in our company. The remote repositories are stored somewhere in a shared folder. We have a contractor who works at home so we want to let him use GIT but he does not have access to our network plus we don't want to provide him with VPN access.

Is there a WEB access software for GIT which allows Checkout/Commit/Push/Pull/Create Branch and other general commands be performed remotely?

Comment: If you don't want to provide the contractor any access to your git in your shared network, why don't you let him work on a private repository (in bitbucket.com for instance), and then manually pull the changes into your repository?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html): it is an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) you can setup on top of git.

You can restrict access per user for given repositories.

But: that implies you have some way to *authenticate* said user when he/she tries to clone/pull/push. You need an [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514823/6309) or [https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12292683/6309) listener in place to access your repos.